# A specific hostname (smtp.office365.com) can't be resolved in a docker user-defined bridge network

Tags: docker, dns, docker-network

With some docker image with nslookup (for example I'm going to use [tutum/dnsutils](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/dnsutils)), if I try this command:

```
docker run -it --rm tutum/dnsutils nslookup smtp.office365.com
```

it returns:

```
Server:         172.25.32.1
Address:        172.25.32.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
smtp.office365.com      canonical name = outlook.office365.com.
outlook.office365.com   canonical name = outlook.ha.office365.com.
outlook.ha.office365.com        canonical name = outlook.ms-acdc.office.com.
outlook.ms-acdc.office.com      canonical name = ITM-efz.ms-acdc.office.com.
Name:   ITM-efz.ms-acdc.office.com
Address: 40.99.9.18
...
```

Then, I create a network by running `docker network create testnet` and try this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --net testnet tutum/dnsutils nslookup smtp.office365.com
```

it returns:

```
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find smtp.office365.com: No answer
```

Why is there such a difference?

If I try these commands with the host `outlook.office365.com`, both successfully return the resolved ip address.

I'm using docker in WSL with these versions:

```
$docker version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:01:58 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 17:59:49 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.12
  GitCommit:        a05d175400b1145e5e6a735a6710579d181e7fb0
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the default behavior of bridge networks:

> By default, traffic from containers connected to the default bridge
> network is not forwarded to the outside world.

Please refer to the [official doc here](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world) to enable forwarding.

Comment: In the question, the external DNS lookup _does_ work using the default bridge network, though, just not a user-defined bridge network.